# ASP.NET Core MVC long running operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, background

I have an ASP.NET Core application that executes a query based on user requested tokens, and is accessing external systems authenticated as the user. This request takes a long time to complete, and I want to make it asynchronous. To be able to do that I was looking into using a background service to offload the work, and to use SignalR to respond to data received events, however I can't find a good way to execute a long running task 'as a user' from an MVC controller action.

What is the preferred / best way to do this? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)? It is the best solution for the long-running background task.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice) which is the aspnet core way to do long running tasks if you want to implement all by yourself, otherwise i also suggest [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I will suggest using the Hangfire as it enables to schedule tasks with a Cron expression. Cron expression will allow you to set tasks with long intervals which can give sufficient time to complete long time tasks.

Comment: That seems to be a comment for the other answer.